# Do packages installed from Github need Rtools?

Tags: r, github, package, devtools

I am creating my first package, which shall be installed through Github. I thought that Rtools was needed only for the person creating it. However, people that tried to install it using Github were asked to update Rtools. Is this really necessary?

Doing some research, I found this: https://community.rstudio.com/t/missing-rtools-should-i-be-worried/27817

One of the answers says the following:

> "This means that if you are going to install packages that need
> compilation, you also have to install Rtools in your system. "

This is the repo with the package: https://github.com/datazoompuc/PNAD_Covid/tree/master/R/datazoom_pnad_covid

What does this actually mean? How do I know that my package needs compilation?

Comment: Can you show the exact command they are running and the exact message they are receiving? I wonder if something is getting lost in translation. Also, might as well also provide a link the the repo in question so we can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: @MrFlick I've added the link

Comment: Thanks for the repo link. It does seem odd that Rtools would be required to install that package. So now i'm really curious again exactly what command are running to install the package and what the specific message is that they are getting and where exactly it's popping up.

Comment: @MrFlick I'll check with some users and will follow up! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought that Rtools was needed only for the person creating it.

Yes, if and only if you distribute it as a *binary*. Then the creator uses Rtools to compile and link, and the user just installs, and enjoys.

That is how CRAN works as CRAN compiles for Windows users.

GitHub, however, is foremost a *source* repository so the installation from GitHub is using a source mode ... and every user will need to compile, and hence have Rtools.  (Unless the package and all its depedencies are R-code only.)

You can also have a *package repository* on GitHub using *e.g.* the [drat](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=drat) package to create it, but that is getting us a little further from the original question.

Comment: The repo in question has been included in the question and it's basically one file of just R code. There's no `src` directory. Is there something else that would make it need to compile?

Comment: And no depends?  In that case the warning would be overzealous.

Comment: There are no "Depends" listed in the DESCRIPTION file. I see some imports: ` dplyr, labelled, purrr, readr, stringr` but those should all be on CRAN. My guess is that the error message isn't being relayed correctly. Maybe it's one of those message that a compiled version of one of those packages is available but a new one is available as source and then they choose to install from source and then get that message? Just wasn't sure if there could be something else going on.

Answer (score 4):

Your package "needs compilation" — i.e. needs Rtools to install from source (on Windows) — if it contains C or Fortran components, i.e. if you have anything in the `src/` directory of your package ...

If you, the package author, don't know if you have C or Fortran code as part of your package, then you almost certainly don't.

It's quite possible that `devtools` is being overzealous, i.e. detecting that users have a not-most-current `Rtools` and suggesting (requiring??) that they update it, even though it's not needed for this installation.

Comment: How can I check this? In terms of dependencies, it only depends on some functions from tidyverse